# Angular testing routes: SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should navigate to /tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

The expected behaviour is that by clicking on my button it should navigate to /tests. My issue is that my expectation in the code below is not read. I also added a picture of my output in Karma below.

```
  it("should navigate to /tests", () => {
    const location = TestBed.get(Location)
    const buttons = de.queryAll(By.css('button')); 
    const nativeButton: HTMLButtonElement = buttons[1].nativeElement; 
    nativeButton.click(); 
    fixture.detectChanges(); 
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/tests')
    });
  });
```

When running "ng test":

[image: Karma displays output in google chrome.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to test an async operation using a synchronous test flow. In your test `expect(location.path()).toBe('/tests')` is executed after `fixture.whenStable()` is resolved but your function finish execution before that happens so you need to tell jasmine to wait for `fixture.whenStable()` to resolve. Easier way is to return the promise so jasmine would know that it has to wait for it to terminate the spec.

```
it("should navigate to /tests", () => {
    const location = TestBed.get(Location)
    const buttons = de.queryAll(By.css('button')); 
    const nativeButton: HTMLButtonElement = buttons[1].nativeElement; 
    nativeButton.click(); 
    fixture.detectChanges(); 
    return fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/tests')
    });
  });
```

For more complex scenarios you can use `async/await` or `done`. [Here](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async) you can read how to implement this.